# What are User I O wait events like 'cell single block physical read', 'cell multiblock physical read', 'direct path read' and 'cell smart table scan'

Tags: oracle

I am learning Oracle DB performance monitoring data. From the dashboards, we have graphs showing User I O wait events and would like to understand what each of these events mean. Any inputs would greatly help
1. cell single block physical read
2. cell multiblock physical read
3. direct path read
4. cell smart table scan

Looking forward for some insights. If any references also helps

Comment: Your question sounds like you need to ask a search engine some questions. After you've done that, I kindly suggest you read [ask] and [example] and then ask a more pointed question.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the [Oracle Wait Events](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/descriptions-of-wait-events.html#GUID-2FDDFAA4-24D0-4B80-A157-A907AF5C68E2) Appendix in the Database Reference.

There are many other sources online that explain Oracle wait events, but you should always start with the manual.